# What are the standard patterns for using the react componentDidMount() method to fetch api data for multiple routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to piece together how I should be using the componentDidMount() method.

- **I am using react, and react router**
- **Backend is firebase cloud functions and firestore**

I have three routes including the parent component (/) - then /someLocation, and /someItem.  In addition, it is possible to go to say /someLocation/someItem.  Initially, I am fetching and setting the state with a get request in componentDidMount().  The issue is that when I refresh the child component, I lose state.

From my research I gather that I have two options or a combination of the two (excluding hash router)

1. Store data in local storage (probably ok for fetching a single record)
2. Make a get request every time the page is refreshed which makes sense for the parent component

What is the most common design pattern for routing in react for these cases, and what requests should be contained in the parent's componentDidMount method?

Thanks!  Any direction, tips, tricks or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
render() {
    const { jobs } = this.state
    const getJobPost = (props) => {
        let slug = props.match.params.slug
        let job = jobs.find((job) => job.slug === slug)
        return <JobPost {...props} job={job} isLoading={this.state.isLoading} />
    }

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={(routeProps) => (
                    <MainJobBoard
                        countryFilter={this.countryFilter}
                        handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
                        filterValue={this.state.filterValue}
                        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                        jobs={jobs}
                        {...routeProps}
                    />
                )}
            />
            <Route exact path="/:location/:slug" render={getJobPost} />
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

Comment: when you are calling componentDidMount you just save data in state of this component?

Comment: yes, I saved the state in the app component (where I am calling componentDidMount)

Comment: can you edit your question with code that you're sending state to child component?

Comment: Yep!  i just added my render method.  Let me know if that helps.  jobs is just an array of job postings

Comment: take a look at [react-redux-firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase) with [redux-firestore](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore)

Comment: @wscourge awesome, thanks!